# How to amend output of List web service call

Tags: 2010, list, web-services, rest

I've configured a 'List' and one of its types is 'Hyperlink or Picture'.

As I'm populating this List type I'm required to enter the 'Web address' & 'description' :

[image]

When I access this List via its rest web service the 'web address' & 'description' is within the same image tag separated by a comma :

```
<d:Image1>http://myurl//myimage.jpg, description 1</d:Image1>
```

How can the image url be just returned and not the description, is it possible to separate these two values into separate xml fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are useful, depending on what you need to do with the returned data. With all the web services, I usually use jQuery and would just do a `.split(", ")[0]` or `.split(", ")[1]` to get the appropriate peice of the data.

If you are processing via xslt, then you do a `substring-before(@thefeld, ", ")`or `substring-after(@thefeld, ", ")`.